# Get Current Activity in Espresso android

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

In case of a test that crosses multiple activities, is there a way to get current activity?

getActivtiy() method just gives one activity that was used to start the test.

I tried something like below,

```
public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    Activity activity = null;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    try {
        Class<?> myClass = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClass();
        activity = (Activity) myClass.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return activity;
}
```

but I get null object.

Comment: I would be happy to have the activity which has started the test but sadly you didn't specify the class name for getActivtiy();

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Espresso, you can use `ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry` but it is not officially supported, so it may not work in future versions.

Here is how it works:

```
Activity getCurrentActivity() throws Throwable {
  getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
  final Activity[] activity = new Activity[1];
  runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      java.util.Collection<Activity> activities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
      activity[0] = Iterables.getOnlyElement(activities);
  }});
  return activity[0];
}
```

Comment: With updates to espresso is there anyway this could be null? I'm not able to get a non-null value from it currently at all, but I use to be able to.

Comment: Use this code for espresso 2.0 http://qathread.blogspot.com/2014/09/discovering-espresso-for-android-how-to.html

Comment: Here is a similar solution in Kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684943/4584212

Comment: Is this approach relevant for AndroidX Test?

Answer (score 30):

If all you need is to make the check against current `Activity`, use may get along with native Espresso one-liner to check that expected intent was launched:

```
intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), ExpectedActivity.class)));
```

Espresso will also show you the intents fired in the meanwhile if not matching yours.

The only setup you need is to replace `ActivityTestRule` with `IntentsTestRule` in the test to let it keep track of the intents launching. And make sure this library is in your `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
```

Comment: I get `I/TestRunner: android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.` Even tho current activity is the same I assert. Espresso `2.2.2`. `@Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<MainScreen> main = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainScreen.class);` And assertion: `intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), MainScreen.class)));`

Comment: how is this answering the question here?

Answer (score 16):

The Android team has replaced `ActivityTestRule` with [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario). We could do `activityTestRule.getActivity()` with `ActivityTestRule` but not with [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario). Here is my work around solution for getting an `Activity` from [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) (inspired by @Ryan and @Fabian solutions)

```
@get:Rule
var activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)
...
private fun getActivity(): Activity? {
  var activity: Activity? = null
  activityRule.scenario.onActivity {
    activity = it
  }
  return activity
}
```

Comment: careful with threading when getting activity with this approach

Comment: If I'm testing an end-to-end flow of several activities, is there a way to get the currently visible activity using ActivityScenario? I only manage to get the initial one.

Answer (score 15):

I like @Ryan's version as it doesn't use undocumented internals, but you can write this even shorter:

```
private Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    final Activity[] activity = new Activity[1];
    onView(isRoot()).check(new ViewAssertion() {
        @Override
        public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
            activity[0] = (Activity) view.getContext();
        }
    });
    return activity[0];
}
```

Please be aware, though that this will not work when running your tests in Firebase Test Lab. That fails with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: Did you manage to find out why this was failing on Firebase Test Lab?

Comment: I don't know specifically why they are doing this, but the view does not hold the activity as its context but instead this DecorContext. Couldn't find any reference to that anywhere, unfortunately

Comment: I have just started using Espresso and I need an idling resource which is not in the first activity. So I am extending idling resource and want to check if my progress bar is showing. The best way I can see to do this is to get the      activity and query this state. I was hoping to run these tests on Firebase.

Comment: I haven't done anything with idling resources yet, but onView() also works after switching to a different activity. Can you maybe just use that inside your idling resource?

Comment: Regarding FireBase issue, use: activity[0] = (Activity) view.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getContext();

Comment: You won't be able to use this *inside* an idling resource. The `check` call will actually check for idle: `uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();` So you'll hit an infinite loop where the idling resource is waiting to get the current activity, which won't be returned until the UI thread is idle, which won't happen because you have a registered idling resource. Found this out the hard way =(

Comment: This also happened on my local device - so i used the activity[0] = (Activity) view.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getContext(); method from user2999943 and it worked

Comment: Why are you creating an array if you always get one activity?

Comment: @GabrielBB because in Java references to variables outside a Lambda are "effectively final" i.e. you can't assign to these variables. The array is a workaround for that. Try replacing it with a simple variable in your favourite IDE to see the error for yourself

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't get any of the other solutions to work, so I ended up having to do this:

Declare your `ActivityTestRule`:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
```

Declare a `final` Activity array to store your activities:

```
private final Activity[] currentActivity = new Activity[1];
```

Add a helper method to register with the application context to get lifecycle updates:

```
private void monitorCurrentActivity() {
    mainActivityTestRule.getActivity().getApplication()
            .registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(final Activity activity, final Bundle savedInstanceState) { }

                @Override
                public void onActivityStarted(final Activity activity) { }

                @Override
                public void onActivityResumed(final Activity activity) {
                    currentActivity[0] = activity;
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityPaused(final Activity activity) { }

                @Override
                public void onActivityStopped(final Activity activity) { }

                @Override
                public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(final Activity activity, final Bundle outState) { }

                @Override
                public void onActivityDestroyed(final Activity activity) { }
            });
}
```

Add a helper method to get the current activity

```
private Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    return currentActivity[0];
}
```

So, once you've launched your first activity, just call `monitorCurrentActivity()` and then whenever you need a reference to the current activity you just call `getCurrentActivity()`

Comment: Best solution! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
public static Activity getActivity() {
    final Activity[] currentActivity = new Activity[1];
    Espresso.onView(AllOf.allOf(ViewMatchers.withId(android.R.id.content), isDisplayed())).perform(new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isAssignableFrom(View.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "getting text from a TextView";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            if (view.getContext() instanceof Activity) {
                Activity activity1 = ((Activity)view.getContext());
                currentActivity[0] = activity1;
            }
        }
    });
    return currentActivity[0];
}
```

Comment: One question: Why are you using an array?

Comment: @GabrielBB because the currentActivity is used inside a anonymus  function, thus have to be final, if final, you can initialise it only in constructor, because of that, you use an "Array".

Answer (score 2):

I improved @Fabian Streitel answer so you can use this method without ClassCastException

```
public static Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    final Activity[] activity = new Activity[1];

    onView(isRoot()).check((view, noViewFoundException) -> {

        View checkedView = view;

        while (checkedView instanceof ViewGroup && ((ViewGroup) checkedView).getChildCount() > 0) {

            checkedView = ((ViewGroup) checkedView).getChildAt(0);

            if (checkedView.getContext() instanceof Activity) {
                activity[0] = (Activity) checkedView.getContext();
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    return activity[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50762439/6007104 here's a Kotlin version of a generic util for accessing current Activity:

```
class CurrentActivityDelegate(application: Application) {
    private var cachedActivity: Activity? = null

    init {
        monitorCurrentActivity(application)
    }

    fun getCurrentActivity() = cachedActivity

    private fun monitorCurrentActivity(application: Application) {
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(
            object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
                override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
                    cachedActivity = activity
                    Log.i(TAG, "Current activity updated: ${activity::class.simpleName}")
                }

                override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
                override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity?) {}
                override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity?) {}
                override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity?) {}
                override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity?, outState: Bundle?) {}
                override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity?) {}
            })
    }
}
```

And then simply use like so:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    currentActivityDelegate = CurrentActivityDelegate(activityTestRule.activity.application)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution proposed by @lacton didn't work for me, probably because activity was not in a state that was reported by `ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry`.

I even tried `Stage.PRE_ON_CREATE` still didn't get any activity.

**Note**: I could not use the `ActivityTestRule` or `IntentTestRule` because I was starting my activity using `activitiy-alias` and didn't make any sense to use the actual class in the tests when I want to test to see if the alias works.

My solution to this was subscribing to lifecycle changes through `ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry` and blocking the test thread until activity is launched:

```
// NOTE: make sure this is a strong reference (move up as a class field) otherwise will be GCed and you will not stably receive updates.
ActivityLifecycleCallback lifeCycleCallback = new ActivityLifecycleCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityLifecycleChanged(Activity activity, Stage stage) {
                classHolder.setValue(((MyActivity) activity).getClass());

                // release the test thread
                lock.countDown();
            }
         };

// used to block the test thread until activity is launched
final CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
final Holder<Class<? extends MyActivity>> classHolder = new Holder<>();
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
   @Override
    public void run() {
        ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().addLifecycleCallback(lifeCycleCallback);
     }
});

// start the Activity
intent.setClassName(context, MyApp.class.getPackage().getName() + ".MyActivityAlias");
context.startActivity(intent);
// wait for activity to start
lock.await();

// continue with the tests
assertTrue(classHolder.hasValue());
assertTrue(classHolder.getValue().isAssignableFrom(MyActivity.class));
```

`Holder` is basically a wrapper object. You can use an array or anything else to capture a value inside the anonymous class.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the only Activity in your test case, you can do:

### 1. declare you test `Rule`

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TestActivity.class);
```

### 2. get you `Activity`:

```
mActivityTestRule.getActivity()
```

That's a piece of pie!

Comment: from the question: "getActivtiy() method just gives one activity that was used to start the test." as opposed to "is there a way to get current activity?", so you didn't answer the question

Comment: Ow, sorry :-) I just was googling how to get an activity and found this question. Cause the question doesn't describe the solution, I just created a new tab and continued my searches. Then, when I had found the solution, I started to close tabs. It seems like I just shared my solution here without any back mind. I hope, it's not so bad to be placed here :-)

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer may not work in many espresso tests. The following works with espresso version 2.2.2 and Android compile/target SDK 27 running on API 25 devices:

```
@Nullable
private Activity getActivity() {
    Activity currentActivity = null;

    Collection resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(RESUMED);
    if (resumedActivities.iterator().hasNext()){
        currentActivity = (Activity) resumedActivities.iterator().next();
    }
    return currentActivity;
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Querying activity state off main thread is not allowed.