# Espresso - How can I check if an activity is launched after performing a certain action?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-espresso

the following is one of my Espresso test cases.

```
    public void testLoginAttempt() {
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.username)).perform(ViewActions.clearText()).perform(ViewActions.typeText("nonexistinguser@krossover.com"));
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.username)).perform(ViewActions.clearText()).perform(ViewActions.typeText("invalidpassword"));

        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.login_button)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        // AFTER CLICKING THE BUTTON, A NEW ACTIVITY WILL POP UP.
        // Clicking launches a new activity that shows the text entered above. You don't need to do
        // anything special to handle the activity transitions. Espresso takes care of waiting for the
        // new activity to be resumed and its view hierarchy to be laid out.
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.action_logout))
                .check(ViewAssertions.matches(not(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed())));

    }
```

Currently what I did was to check if a view in the new activity (R.id.action_logout) is visibible or not. If visible, I will assume tha the activity opened successfully.
But it doesn't seem to work as I expected.
Is there a better way to check if a new activity is successfully launched instead of checking a view in that activity is visible?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you import ViewMatchers? `import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*`

Comment: @user2062024 Can you post the working code?

Comment: The newest Espresso will automatically waits for Asyntask.

Answer (score 79):

You can use:

```
intended(hasComponent(YourExpectedActivity.class.getName()));
```

Requires this gradle entry:

```
androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion")
```

The import for the `intended()` and `hasComponent()`

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent;
```

as mentioned by Shubam Gupta please remember to call `Intents.init()` before calling `intended()`. You can eventually call it in the `@Before` method.

Comment: hmm, nowadays android official docs don't mention the `Intents.init()` thing, and in my single case it works perfectly without this. What's the proper solution then?

Comment: Finally, you need to release `Intents` in within `@After` like  `Intents.release()`

Comment: If you are new to this, be sure to read Shubhams answer below also.

Comment: If you already migrated to AndroidX then it's `androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0"`

Comment: import statement for androidx is `androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended`

Answer (score 25):

Try:

`intended(hasComponent(YourActivity.class.getName()));`

Also, keep in mind

`java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown if `Intents.init()` is not called before `intended()`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the init() thing!

Answer (score 12):

You may do it as follows:

```
    @Test
public void testLoginAttempt() {
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.username)).perform(ViewActions.clearText()).perform(ViewActions.typeText("nonexistinguser@example.com"));
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.username)).perform(ViewActions.clearText()).perform(ViewActions.typeText("invalidpassword"));

    Intents.init();
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.login_button)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    Intents.release();
}
```

`java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown if `Intents.init()` is not called.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that your application performs the network operation after you click login button. Espresso doesn't handle (wait) network calls to finish by default. You have to implement your custom IdlingResource which will block the Espresso from proceeding with tests until IdlingResource returns back in Idle state, which means that network request is finished. Take a look at Espresso samples page - https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/samples/index.html

Comment: Updated the outdated link

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup.html) intent library is in the gradle dependencies

```
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1"
```

Then import these two in your test file

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent
```

Then add [IntentsTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/rule/IntentsTestRule.html) in your test class

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val mainActivityRule = IntentsTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

Finally check the activity has launched intent

```
@Test
fun launchActivityTest() {
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.nav_wonderful_activity))
            .perform(click())

    intended(hasComponent(WonderfulActivity::class.java!!.getName()))
}
```

Comment: IntentsTestRule is deprecated rigth now. You should use Intents.init() as mentioned above in conjunction with ActivityScenarioRule.

Comment: If you already migrated to AndroidX then it's `androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0"`

Answer (score 7):

Try with

```
intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), ExpectedActivity.class)));
```

Look at [response from @riwnodennyk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517291/get-current-activity-in-espresso-android/34084377#34084377)

Comment: Why is `new ComponentName` necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
// The IntentsTestRule class initializes Espresso Intents before each test, terminates the host activity, and releases Espresso Intents after each test
    @get:Rule
    var tradersActivity: IntentsTestRule<TradersActivity> = IntentsTestRule(TradersActivity::class.java)
    @get:Rule
    var jsonViewActivity: IntentsTestRule<JsonViewActivity> = IntentsTestRule(JsonViewActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun scrollToItemAndClick() {
     onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(ITEM_POS, click()))

        // check is activity was started
        intended(hasComponent(JsonViewActivity::class.java.getName()))
    }
```

Answer (score -8):

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class WelcomeActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity() {
        WelcomeActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(WelcomeActivity.class);
        activity.findViewById(R.id.login).performClick();

        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
        assertThat(shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity()).isEqualTo(expectedIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about Espresso, not Robolectric.