# How can I test that when i click a button a n ew Activity is displayed?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, android-testing

In android I have a sample application with 2 Activities, MainActivity and DetailsActivity. In main activity, there is a list and a button, by pressing it the Details Activity is opened. In the intent, I put an ArrayList and an Object.

How can I Test that it works? Espresso Is it ok?

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'



@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class FirstTest {
    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(
            MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void changeText_sameActivity() {

        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());
        // How can i Specify the intent to the new Detail Activity?
    intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), InsectDetailsActivity.class)));


        onView(withId(R.id.tv_original_title))
                .check(matches(withText( /* The text depends on the Passing Intent*/)));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998659/espresso-how-can-i-check-if-an-activity-is-launched-after-performing-a-certain). Here is the answer from that question:

```
intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(),ExpectedActivity.class)))
```

Comment: I make some editings. I got an Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents. And how can i pass all the intends Extras ? Should i create a mock ArrayList and Object to pass them to  the newly created Activity, (Thanks)

Comment: You have to use intending with intended. Also you should use different test case for assertions related to different activities.