# Check activity is opened or crashed mockito

Tags: java, mockito, android-testing

This question is about android unit test MVP
In test class i need to call openactivity method which is in presenter class

and that method will open an activity using view.openCheckoutShippingActivity() method .
How to check is it opened or not using mockito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform unit tests on Android specific elements. You should use instrumented tests. These tests run on a device or emulator. Android's official instrumented test framework is [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso). It's pretty easy actually. An example:

```
@Test
fun greeterSaysHello() {
    onView(withId(R.id.name_field)).perform(typeText("Steve"))
    onView(withId(R.id.greet_button)).perform(click())
    onView(withText("Hello Steve!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

That's from the official documentation.

As for your specific question, please refer tho [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998659/espresso-how-can-i-check-if-an-activity-is-launched-after-performing-a-certain).

And also be careful, this tests run under the `androidtest` package and not in the `test` package.

**Edit**

> i need to call openactivity method which is in presenter class and
>   that method will open an activity

I'm not sure if you are doing it right. The activity should open from the `View` and not from the `Presenter`.

Comment: can help me with an example to make http responce with mockito ?

Comment: what to do ? what is the max coverage for unit test in android with mvp

Comment: Refer to this [one](https://medium.com/mindorks/efficient-android-testing-using-wiremock-and-espresso-cf2d7b7c735f)

Comment: question updated with clarification about your doubt

Comment: in that case that activity has nothing to do with the presenter. just call your `openCheckoutShippingActivity()` on your espresso test

Comment: Would you please suggest good tutorial  to learn android unit test using MVP

Comment: Unit testing has nothing to do with the Architecture. Unit testing has to do with testing the smallest unit. I have followed one and helped me a lot. But it's a paid test. You may contact the lecturer for a discount, and believe me, it really helped me a lot : https://www.udemy.com/professional-android-unit-testing/learn/lecture/11929774?start=0#overview