# How can I check if the new activity was started

Tags: android, testing, coded-ui-tests, android-espresso

Scenario:

1. The user starts the app
2. The user goes to the "CreateAccountActivity"
3. In order to use the application the user has to enter the email and a password
4. The user clicks "create" which switches to the next activity.

   ```
   @Test
   public void createAccountAndLogIn() {
       onView(withId(R.id.login_create)).perform(click());
       onView(withId(R.id.create_email)).perform(clearText(),typeText("xxx@gmail.com"));
       onView(withId(R.id.create_pass)).perform(clearText(),typeText("pass"));
       onView(withId(R.id.create_pass_repeat)).perform(clearText(),typeText("pass"));
       onView(withId(R.id.create_create_button)).perform(click());
   }
   ```

How to check, after the last line, if the new "MainActivity" was launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using [ActivityLifecycleMonitor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/lifecycle/ActivityLifecycleMonitor.html) ... However it will not be a "black box" approach that you are looking for.

If you want to go full black box, asserting the view on the next activity should be sufficient enough to pass a test.

Here is the same question that has more detailed explanation.

[Is there any way to know if an activity has been started with Espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891794/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-an-activity-has-been-started-with-espresso/)

Comment: At least this does not required changes in the Acitivity`s code.

Answer (score 0):

> You can control this defining a variable in Application class. When you define a variable in Application class , variable be protected until your app kill and you can reach this variable every class in project. I think it resolves your problem.

Comment: You're right, but it is more like a "hack" than "solution". I was wondering if espresso supports this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using onResume() method as a quick hack in your MainActivity? Have a `boolean` variable which changes to `true` in `onResume()` and `false` in `onPause()`.

Cheers,
SSG

Comment: I like to test it in a "blackbox" way - you're probably right, but this will not do the job for me.