# How to Espresso Test in Android If an Acitivy was Started

Tags: android, testing, tdd, android-espresso

Can someone teach me how to test the sample code below?

How to I write espresso test for this? Since no view action is required?

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I would want to test whether the activity was actually started. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered multiple times:

1. From obtaining the activity at the time of test execution:

[How can I check if the new activity was started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155638/how-can-i-check-if-the-new-activity-was-started)

2. To the usage of `espresso-intents` artifact (preferred option):

[How to validate whether opened correct activity - Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153146/how-to-validate-whether-opened-correct-activity-espresso/)

Keep in mind that the usage of `IntentsTestRule` might be problematic here, it used to call `Intents.init()` after your activity is launched, which will be too late as you will already be in the new activity. Not sure if this behavior is still in place, but you can work this around by calling `init()` manually in `@Before` method of your test class, don't forget to do `Intents.release()` in your teardown

Comment: Thank you very much. For my specific question, I had to setup the Intent.init() at the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` (for teardown) for my test to pass. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Example with Intents.intending(should be before the launch):

```
@get:Rule
var mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity::class.java, false, false)

@Before
fun before() {
    Intents.init()
}

@After
fun after() {
    Intents.release()
}

@Test
fun whenStartWithUser_shouldOpenHomeScreen() {
    val matcherIntent = hasComponent(HomeActivity::class.java.name)

    Intents.intending(matcherIntent).respondWith(Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null))
    mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(Intent())
    Intents.intended(matcherIntent)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Read the documentation about `Log` and `Logcat`. You can track all the actions taking place there.

Comment: Thats not what i was referring to. I was actually refferibg to wrinting a espresso code to verify this.

Comment: Log.d("this your TAG", "This your message");