# Whats the difference between intending vs intended in Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Its been 2 weeks since I am studying Espresso and I could not grasp `intending` and `intended`. When do I use `intending` and `intended`? The provided example and online tutorials are not helping and researching the web is doing me more damage than good.

Semantically, for intellectual reference, why is it `intend-ing` and the other `intended`, this added more to the confusion. Is this another Google naming blunder or it's just me? These two methods really don't make sense.

I am misunderstanding its usage. [I wanted to test if my activity `A` launched activity `B`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891794/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-an-activity-has-been-started-with-espresso). That's it. Here is my code:

```
@Test
public void shouldLaunchTagListActivity()
{
    onView(withId(R.id.edittext_description_minimized))
            .perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.linearlayout_add_note_maximize))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    onView(withId(R.id.relativelayout_quick_action_button))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    onView(withId(R.id.imagebutton_tag))
            .perform(click());

    // should I intended or intending here?
    // ???
    intended(toPackage(HomeScreenActivity.class.getName()));

    onView(withId(R.id.coordinatorlayout_tag_list))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

This test always passes even I supplant the intent with the wrong the target.

I can check if the other activity has been launched by checking if my target view is existing and was seen by the user. But now I am going to run on a different user story where I really need to check if the activity sent the request to launched another activity (my activity, not external).

Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The difference is `Intended` only verifies that an Intent was launched (what you want).  `Intending` will return a result when the Intent is launched.

For `Intended` (if you want to check if the intent did actually launched your activity)

```
intended(hasComponent(TagListActivity.class.getName()));
```

This will fail if you press a button and launched, say, MyActivity, and you test `intended` for TagListActivity. It will throw this following error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.
```

Now, if you were testing that `onActivityResult` was handled properly, you would use `Intending` and pass in an `ActivityResult` similar to this:

```
Intent resultData = new Intent();
resultData.putExtra("resultData", "fancyData");
ActivityResult result = new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);

intending(toPackage(HomeScreenActivity.class.getName())).respondWith(result));

// Perform action that throws the Intent
onView(withId(R.id.imagebutton_tag)).perform(click());

// Verify your Activity is in the state it should be here.
```

So in this case, if you were expecting "HomeScreenActivity" to return something, you would use `Intending`.

Comment: @NeonWarge: To answer the semantics question, I believe it's because `Intending` doesn't actually verify, and you set it up *before* the Intent is thrown so the result will be returned.  Where as `Intended` is verified *after* the Intent is thrown.

Comment: Thank you, that is very clear. I will edit your answer to add something about `intending` I was able to make my test work now.

Comment: Please verify my edit, if it is wrong, ignore it and then correct my understanding if possible. Thanks!