# Espresso - how to get current activity to test Fragments?

Tags: android, android-testing, ui-testing, android-espresso

I have been playing around with `Espresso` tests for couple weeks now and I finally decided to start testing Fragments.

Immediately I ran into a problem, how do I get current activity?

My app uses data from login so I can't launch the activity with test rule.
 Simply put, is there something similar to `getActivity()` when doing espresso tests?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I usually get it like this, it looks (and probably is) hacky but, hey, it works

```
import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;

public class MyTest {

    private Activity getActivityInstance(){
        final Activity[] currentActivity = {null};

        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Collection<Activity> resumedActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
                Iterator<Activity> it = resumedActivity.iterator();
                currentActivity[0] = it.next();
            }
        });

        return currentActivity[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: but how use this solve?
for example now i used like this : `val activity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity()
        val idlingResource = ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(activity)`

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand your problem

Comment: Sorry for my english) i mean how i can call yours method in another class?

Comment: you just add this method to your class :)

Comment: For example MyTest.getActivityInstance() doesn t work(

Answer (score 7):

Here is [lelloman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990078/4584212) with a slight change in Kotlin:

```
import android.app.Activity
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation
import androidx.test.runner.lifecycle.ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry
import androidx.test.runner.lifecycle.Stage

object EspressoHelper {
    fun getCurrentActivity(): Activity? {
        var currentActivity: Activity? = null
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync { run { currentActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED).elementAtOrNull(0) } }
        return currentActivity
    }
}
```