# Espresso broadcasting intents manually

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have an espresso test I'm writing for a feature, and the feature uses a broadcast receiver filtering the [Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) action.  Essentially, the onReceive(..) is triggered every minute by the system, and my UI may or may not update.  Problem is, my UI test right now has to sleep for 1 minute to ensure the onReceive(..) has triggered at least once before executing a statement assuming the onReceive(..) has triggered the UI update.

I want to get rid of the sleep code and manually trigger the onReceive(..) on behalf of the system, but Android documents this is not possible with [Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK).

> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Is it possible to achieve what I want or perhaps a different approach entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up referencing the top most activity running, and broadcasting the message itself.  I was able to do this because the implementation lives in the base activity which all activities extend from.  The method `getCurrentActivity()` implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737127/espresso-how-to-get-current-activity-to-test-fragments).

```
public static void triggerACTION_TICK_BROADCAST() {
    Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        if (activity instanceof BaseActivity) {
            BaseActivity baseActivity = (BaseActivity) activity;
            BroadcastReceiver tickReceiver = baseActivity.getTickReceiver();
            if (tickReceiver != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
                tickReceiver.onReceive(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```