# How test code that depends on an Activity

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-activity, android-resources

I have written code to make screenshots on Android and I am trying to write a test for this. When running the test method, then I receive the following error message: `Activity never becomes requested state "[STARTED, CREATED, DESTROYED, RESUMED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")`. I have a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong.

The production code has been tested manually.

My test code in `src/androidTest/java/org/app`:

```
@RunWith (AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ScreenshotsCaptorTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<TestActivity> rule =
        new ActivityScenarioRule<>(TestActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // This line is never reached
        ActivityScenario<TestActivity> scenario = rule.getScenario();
        scenario.onActivity(activity -> {
            activity.setCallback(() -> {
                try {
                    Bitmap screenshot = ScreenshotsCaptorBuilder.captor.takeScreenshot();
                    // Assert screenshot is non-null
                } catch (CaptureScreenshotFailedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });

            Intent intent = ScreenshotsCaptorBuilder.intent(activity);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        });
    }
}
```

My helper Activity in `src/androidTest/java/org/app`:

```
import org.app.test.R;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private Callback callback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // This line is never reached
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }

    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        // This line is never reached
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        // This line is never reached
        ScreenshotsCaptorBuilder.createCaptor(this, resultCode, intent);
        callback.done();
    }

    public interface Callback {
        // This line is never reached
        void done();
    }
}
```

The `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="org.app">

    <application>
        <activity
                android:name=".TestActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And `src/androidTest/res/layout/activity_test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It would be really helpful if someone provide me some suggestions or tips to resolve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Weirdly, the only other relevant page I found on the matther is [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53638398/3459089) from 2 years ago where someone claims it was fixed in some release soon after. However, I still have the bug in 1.3.0. and it seems, [we're not the only ones](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/143#issuecomment-674409060).

In the meantime, I use the solution described her as a bypass : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60341723/3459089

Comment: Seems related issue-thread: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/940 (but ignore that the poster thinks the issue is related to release-builds only)