# Espresso : How to test background drawable of an ImageButton

Tags: android, android-espresso, imagebutton

I seemed to have hit rock bottom trying to find a solution of how I can test that my ImageButton has a certain Background drawable in my Espresso test. But I keep getting an error which I pasted below. I've provided as much of the code I can that I thought was relevant.

ImageButton

```
            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_background_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_error" android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_okay" android:state_activated="false" />
</selector>
```

Custom Matcher:

```
fun matchColor(expectedId: Int): Matcher<View> {
return object : BoundedMatcher<View, ImageButton>(ImageButton::class.java) {
    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("with text color: ")
        description?.appendValue(expectedId)
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: ImageButton?): Boolean {
        return item?.context?.resources?.getDrawable(expectedId)?.constantState == item?.drawable?.constantState
    }

}
```

}

Test:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.image_button)).check(matches(matchColor(R.drawable.ic_background_okay)))
```

I get the following error:

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text 
color: <2131165331>' doesn't match the selected view. Expected: with text color: 
<2131165331>Got: "AppCompatImageButton{id=2131296363, ...}
```

Comment: I am planning to write a solution to this,but are you also having problems with imageviews? Or all of your problems are related to ImageButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to set tags whenever you change the image changes and compare the tags instead of the images itself. If you are not setting tags and can't figure out how to write a custom matcher, you can find your imagebutton via activity and use the same logic you use in your application to compare which image is present right now.

```
@Test
fun test_image_button_compare_success() {
    val activity = getActivityInstance();
    val imageButton = activity?.findViewById((R.id.image_button)) as ImageButton
    assertTrue(1 == 1) //Replace here with your control using image button
}
```

Getting activity instance is [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737127/espresso-how-to-get-current-activity-to-test-fragments/58684943#58684943)

```
private Activity getActivityInstance() {
    final Activity[] currentActivity = {null};

    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Collection<Activity> resumedActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
            Iterator<Activity> it = resumedActivity.iterator();
            currentActivity[0] = it.next();
        }
    });

    return currentActivity[0];
}
```

Comment: Isn't it junit test? it not even purposely to test using espresso

Answer (score 0):

For anyone want to find solution to check drawable selector(StateListDrawable) using Espresso

```
object CurrentDrawableMatcher {
  var expectedDrawable: Drawable? = null
  var width: Int? = null
  var height: Int? = null
 val viewBackgroundMatcher = object : BoundedMatcher<View, View>(View::class.java) {
    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        description.appendText("with current drawable: $expectedDrawable")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: View): Boolean {
        val currentDrawable = (item.background.current) ?: return false
        return compareDrawables(
            currentDrawable.current,
            expectedDrawable?.current,
            width,
            height
        )
    }
}

fun compareDrawables(
    drawable1: Drawable?,
    drawable2: Drawable?,
    width: Int? = null,
    height: Int? = null
): Boolean {
    if (drawable1 == null && drawable2 == null) {
        return true
    } else if (drawable1 == null || drawable2 == null) {
        return false
    }
    val bitmap1 = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable1, width, height)
    val bitmap2 = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable2, width, height)
    return bitmap1.sameAs(bitmap2)
}

fun getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable: Drawable, width: Int? = null, height: Int? = null): Bitmap {
    if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
        return drawable.bitmap
    }
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        width ?: drawable.intrinsicWidth,
        height ?: drawable.intrinsicHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    drawable.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```