# Get resource from Android test: InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext() VS myActivityTestRule.getActivity()

Tags: android, android-testing, android-junit, androidjunitrunner

I need to get resource from Android test (AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner). What is the recommended way and why?

```
String some_res_string = 
androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
.getTargetContext().getString(R.string.some_res_string);
```

or

```
 String some_res_string = myActivityTestRule.getActivity() //Activity
                        .getString(R.string.some_res_string);
```

Full code

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> myActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class, true, true);

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String some_res_string = myActivityTestRule.getActivity() //Activity
                .getString(R.string.some_res_string);

        String some_res_string2 =
                androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
                        .getTargetContext().getString(R.string.some_res_string);
    }

}
```

Comment: ActivityTestRule replaced with [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule) . And there is no direct way of getting activity from `ActivityScenarioRule` which i can find [Except This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041319/4168607). So i guess `InstrumentationRegistry` is way to go IMO.

Comment: @ADM, ActivityTestRule exists and not deprecated if use @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think getting the Context from the InstrumentationRegistry directly is deprecated. The [ApplicationProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider) should be used instead.

```kotlin
getApplicationContext().getString(resId)
```

Comment: No, The androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation() not deprecated